# Seeking Advice for Efficient Scene Management in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Hey fellow JavaFX enthusiasts,

I'm in need of some guidance regarding scene management in JavaFX. I've been working on a project that involves multiple scenes, and I'm looking for a more efficient way to handle the switching between these scenes. Unfortunately, the current solution I've implemented in my SceneManager file seems to be falling short, particularly when it comes to transitioning beyond the first scene.

Here's a brief overview of my situation: I have several scenes in my JavaFX application, and I want to smoothly switch between them based on user interactions or application events. While I initially implemented a SceneManager class to handle this task, I'm experiencing some limitations with it. It works fine for the first scene transition, but subsequent transitions don't seem to work as expected.

Here is how I set up my main block:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private SceneManager sceneManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        sceneManager = new SceneManager(primaryStage);

        Image icon = new Image("icon.png");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
        primaryStage.setTitle("First Project");

        sceneManager.switchToStartmenu();

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And here's a simplified version of my SceneManager class:

```
public class SceneManager {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Scene startmenu;
    private Scene gameoptions;

    public SzenenManager() {}
    public SzenenManager(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public void createStartmenu() throws IOException {
        Parent startmenuContent = fxmlLoadingMethod.loadFXML("startmenu.fxml");

        if (startmenuContent != null) {
            startmenu = new Scene(startmenuContent);
        }
    }

    public void createGameoptions() throws IOException {
        Parent gameoptionsContent = fxmlLoadingMethod.loadFXML("gameoptions.fxml");

        if (gameoptionsContent != null) {
            gameoptions = new Scene(gameoptionsContent);
        }
    }


    public void switchToStartmenu() throws IOException {
        createStartmenu();
        primaryStage.setScene(startmenu);
    }

    public void switchToGameoptions() throws IOException {
        createGameoptions();
        primaryStage.setScene(gameoptions);
    }
```

While this setup works for the first scene transition, subsequent transitions don't seem to work as expected. I believe the issue lies in the fact that I cannot call the switchScenes() method in the SceneManager if I have the stage set in my main block. This coupling between the main block and SceneManager is causing inefficiencies and making it difficult to find a solution.

I'm confident that there must be a more elegant approach to solving this problem. I'm seeking suggestions and ideas from the community to help me improve the scene management in my application. Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on the following:

How can I decouple the SceneManager from the main block to allow smooth transitions between scenes?
Are there any design patterns or best practices that can be applied to enhance the scene management in JavaFX applications?
Is there a recommended way to handle the switching of scenes while still having access to the primaryStage instance?

Thank you all for your time and support.

Edit:
I forgot to mention this:
I am using my SceneManager as the controller in all .fxml files.

Comment: *"I am using my SceneManager as the controller in all .fxml files."* This is not the correct approach. Each FXML file should have its own controller class. And the `SceneManager` is not really a controller either. Use some kind of MVC or MVC-like (MVP, MVVM, etc) design: see if [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/bae73788a9b881cf9358cbf2d842f554) helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful message! Your suggestion to explore the MVC design pattern, which I wasn't aware of before, has opened up a whole new perspective for me. The example with an MVC-like approach has proven to be incredibly helpful in addressing my concerns. Thanks!